# Как обратится к елементу, jquery

Tags: jquery, css

Есть конструкция типа

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <a href="#">123</a>
    <div class="qwerty">456</div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">123</a>
    <div class="qwerty">456</div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">123</a>
    <div class="qwerty">456</div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Надо что бы при наведении на ссылку показывался блок, как к нему обратиться можно через jquery?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Например с помощью `.next()`:

```js
$('a').hover(
  function(){ $(this).next('.qwerty').show()},
  function(){ $(this).next('.qwerty').hide()}
);
```

```css
.qwerty {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.js"></script>

  <ul>
  <li>
    <a href="#">123</a>
    <div class="qwerty">456</div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">123</a>
    <div class="qwerty">456</div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">123</a>
    <div class="qwerty">456</div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

а, вообще, можно и просто css:

```css
.qwerty {
  display: none;
}

a:hover~.qwerty,
.qwerty:hover {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <a href="#">123</a>
    <div class="qwerty">456</div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">123</a>
    <div class="qwerty">456</div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">123</a>
    <div class="qwerty">456</div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Отлично, спасибо) Еще вопросик, а как сделать, что бы элемент не пропадал сразу как отводишь курсор с ссылки, а пропадал когда уводишь с скрываемого елемента

Comment: `a:hover~.qwerty,
.qwerty:hover {display: block;}`